# Restrictions on addictive design in software

Tags: software

Are there any restrictions on what a software can actually do design-wise?
A comparison to make here, for example, is that casinos have to inform their patrons of the dangers of gambling, or they have to kick people out if they seem too "addicted."

Is there any equivalent of this in software design, specifically about designing it to be addictive (excluding online gambling)?

Comment: This really would be dependent on a country or locality. China for example is starting to take a hard line on addictive gaming, USA less so.

Comment: Some app stores have restrictions and rules that dictate design guidelines, most notably Apple's app store has a number of rules which forbid certain types of apps or restrict the design in some way. But those are not legal requirements, just a requirement if you want to put your software in the particular app store. I couldn't find anything about 'addictive' design in their guidelines, though.